# how to render ecmascript 6 with python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ecmascript-6, render

I try to run ECMAScript 6 with python

I already try that

```
from quickjs import Function
from py_mini_racer import py_mini_racer
import execjs
import js2py
import requests_html

js = """
function test(){
    document.write(`
    """+html+"""`);
return document.documentElement?.innerHTML
}
//test()
"""

result = js2py.eval_js(js)
print(result)
```

TemplateElement is not supported by ECMA 5.1.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/Js2Py/): `eval_js6()`

Comment: didn't work....

Comment: It doesn't work because the JavaScript you're trying to execute requires a browser context that's not present.

Comment: So how u suggest me to run that?

Comment: Try [`py_mini_racer`](https://github.com/sqreen/PyMiniRacer). It works for me.